# Как убрать прерывание аудио при перезагрузке страницы?

Tags: html, html5, кэширование, аудио

Здравствуйте,интересует вопрос: как можно сделать так,чтобы при перезагрузке проигрываемая музыка не начинала играть заново(сохранялось время остановки(как с видео на youtube))
Мне советовали воспользоватся событием onunload(),но я не знаю как такое реализовать. Можете показать как делать?

Answer (score 0):

Можно использовать localStorage для хранения currentTime аудиотрека. И по событию onunload() обновлять это время (***здесь пример не воспроизводится,
 закрыт доступ к localStorage - скопируйте код на свою локальную страницу)***:

```js
var pl = document.getElementById('player');
var playTime = localStorage.getItem('time'); //получаем значение времени трека из локального хранилища
if(playTime == null) { //если значение не установлено...
  pl.currentTime = 0.0; //запускаем трек с самого начала
}
else { //если какое-то значение есть...
  pl.currentTime = playTime; //перемещаем бегунок на эту позицию...
}
pl.play(); //...и запускаем воспроизведение
window.onunload = function(){ //в случае закрытия или перезагрузки страницы
  localStorage.setItem('time', pl.currentTime); //записываем в хранилище время трека, на котором прервались
}
```

```html
<audio id="player" src="http://files.realmusic.ru/download/1577511/id195399_-_bi-2_feat._Oxxxymiron_-_pora_vozvraschatsya_domoi_(lyric_video).mp3" controls></audio>
```